# How to import data file for UFT API testing?

Tags: c#, automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft

I am working on a project which requires to dynamically import the test data on run time and run the API test corresponding to the test data.

I tried using XMLload which I directly load from the xml request. This seems to be working fine.

But like GUI testing, where we import the test data, I want the same for API testing - where I can import a excel from an external source dynamically and give the values to the request.

How can I do this?

Comment: An example would be great, as it would be rather useless to run API tests **not** corresponding to the test data ... I think there is at the moment no substantial content in the question to trigger usefull answers or hints.

Comment: I have tried to dynamically import an xml file directly using stserviceactivity.inputenvelope.loadxml - which is not working.

I also tried to load the excel file by using "read from file" in the standard activities. - but I am not sure how I will read the excel from this.

apologies as I am not able to provide any screenshots. Let me know if I can give a better picture.

Comment: The loadxml seems to be working fine. I created a string for the request and provided it to the function. It dynamically loads the request during runtime.

But the same can be done using excel ?

Comment: I'm a little unsure about what you are asking - if you want to load an excel file at runtime, you can just use `Datatable.Import("pathToFile")` to do exactly that?

Comment: You do need to give a better picture.  This is very unclear.  Are you having problems importing an excel file from your api?  When you say "is not working", what does that mean?  are you getting an error?  You need to do a lot better at explaining what your problem is.

Comment: Hello Dave, That is for GUI testing which we are using ? I am trying to get the file imported using API test with C#.

Comment: Hello AgapwIesu, I was trying all options to get the API test to read data from the external source. in my first try I could not get the xml file to load during runtime. But was able to fix that by stserviceactivity.inputenvelope.loadxml. 

I am looking to import the excel using similar method suggested by Dave but for API testing using C#.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, you want to load test data from Excel file. And that is what I have done in my previous project but little differently, so I hope this will be some what useful to you.

These steps will help you drive your test from Excel file where you will provide the location of request XML files and other test data, for example:

- Execution flag
- WSDL
- End Point address
- Environment
- and so on...

=========================================================================
***Steps to import data from Excel file:***

Open **`Data`** pane (View -> Data)
Click **`on New Data Source`**

[image]

Select **`Database`** (Don't worry we'll be using Excel as Database)
New window will appear to **`Set Database Connection`**
Click on **`Build Connection String`** icon

[image]
Click on **`Provider`** tab if not selected
Select **`Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider`**
Click **`Next`**
In **`Data Source`** section, provide the path to your Excel (**`.XLSX`**) file and leave everything to default on this (Connection) tab
Click on **`Advanced`** tab
Select **`Read Write`** from **`Access permissions`** section
Go to **`All`** tab
Select **`Extended Properties`** and click on **`Edit Value`**
Type **`Excel 12.0 Xml`** in **`Property Value`** field and hit **`OK`**
Now go back to **`Connection`** tab and click on **`Test Connection`** button
It should show **`Test connection succeeded`** message, if NOT than go back and follow all the steps again
Click on **`OK`**
Click **`Next`**
Provide the sheet name (that you want to import) in **`Data Source name`** field
For example: **`[TEST_DATA$]`** where **`TEST_DATA`** is a sheet name
Type in your SQL query in big box just above **`Check SQL Statement`** button
*For example:*
I want to import all the rows from TEST_DATA sheet where Execution_Flag   column is having Y value. And SQL statement for that I've used:

```
SELECT * FROM [TEST_DATA$] WHERE Execution_Flag = 'Y'
```

Click on **`Check SQL Statement`** button and it should to show the resulted rows in new **`Query Preview`** window
Close **`Query Preview`** window and click on Finish on **`Set SQL Statement`** window
Now you should see resulted rows in Data pane
* What I like about this approach is if you'll make changes in Excel file and refresh the Data pane, it will automatically update the data in **`Data`** pane

=========================================================================
***Now to read the data from Excel file:***
*Let's say I want to read my request XML file from location specified in Excel file (which we have imported)

I am using **`Read From File activity`***
***Note: This is just an example to give an idea***

Drag and drop **`Read From File activity`** in your work area
This will complain that path is not specified for the file from which to read in **Errors** pane
Double click this message and it will highlight the field for you in **`Properties`** pane
Hover your mouse on Value field next to File path and click on last icon **`Link to data source`**  and this will open **`Select Link Source for 'File path'`** window
Click on **`Data source column`** radio button and then click on **`TEST_DATA`** from **`Select a data source`** section
Select the corresponding column name from **`Select data`** section and click **`OK`**, like shown in image

[image]

=========================================================================
Similarly you can pass value/s to Custom Code from Excel file through Data pane by linking data source and passing it as input and in custom code you can retrieve the value this way:

```
string environmentName = CodeActivity18.Input.Environment_Name;
```

And same way you can write to Excel file as an output from custom code:

```
string finalResponseXMLPath = "some path";
CodeActivity18.Output.ResponseXML_FinalPath = finalResponseXMLPath;
```

Comment: Thanks for spending sometime to provide this. Yes, It is very helpful.

Comment: I will try this out and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help... :)